# How to remove vertical line at x-axis and add labels to plotly subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I have been trying to create subplots using plotly library. I have done most the part but wondering how to add following things:

1. Remove vertical line at x=0 on right hand side scatterplot.
2. Add xlabel and ylabels to left and right figures.

   - histogram
   - xlabel = value, ylabel = counts
   - scatterplot
   - xlabel = value, ylabe = empirical cdf

Here is my code so far:

```py
import numpy as np

import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.plotly as pyp
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.tools as tls
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)


np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.binomial(10, 0.3, 10000)
x, y = np.sort(data), np.arange(1, len(data)+1) / len(data)
idx = np.abs(y-0.5).argmin()
z = x[idx]


hist0 = go.Histogram(x = data,name='Histogram')
sc1 = go.Scatter(x=x,y=y,mode = 'markers',name = 'Empirical CDF')
sc2 = go.Scatter(x=x,y=[0.5]*len(x),mode = 'lines',name = 'y=0.5 (central tendency)')
sc3 = go.Scatter(x=[z]*1000,y=np.linspace(0,1,1000),mode = 'lines',name = 'x={:.2f}'.format(z))


fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_xaxes=True,
                                subplot_titles=('Histogram','Empirical CDF'))

fig.append_trace(hist0, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(sc1, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(sc2, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(sc3, 1, 2)

fig['layout'].update(height=400, width=800, title='')


iplot(fig)
```

The output:
[image]

## Questions

- How to remove vertical x=0 line in right hand side plot
- How go give xlabel and ylabels to these two sub plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using `plotly` version 4:

- You can remove the vertical x=0 line with `fig.update_xaxes(row=1, col=2, zeroline=False)`
- You can label the axes with `fig.update_xaxes(row=1, col=1, title="title")` (substituting `yaxes` for `xaxes` and setting the appropriate titles for `row`/`col`

Documentation links for [subplots](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/) and [axes](https://plot.ly/python/axes)

If you're using version 3:

- you can remove the zero-line from any x-axis with `fig.layout.xaxis<n>.zeroline=False` (setting `n` appropriately, likely `2` in this case)
- you can set the title of any axis with `fig.layout.<dim>axis<n>.title="title"` (setting `dim` and `n` appropriately, such as `yaxis1` etc)

Comment: I am using plotly3 and gives error `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'update_xaxes'`. How to fix this in plotly3.6 ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend upgrading to version 4, which will also allow you to drop the whole `plotly.offline`/`init_notebook_mode` dance :)

Comment: Thanks for kind advice, I have plotly4.0 in my laptop, but in Office computer I am not permitted to upgrade to plolty4 due to other dependencies. So ,I was kind of looking for a  portable solution.

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer to include version 3.x-compatible instructions.